# Xamarin.Forms dynamic layout depending on screen orientation or size

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Did Xamarin.Forms already contain a control/layout which orders it's content depending on the screen orientation or size?

What I want:
Two stacklayouts which are ordered horizontal, if the screen got enough space.
When the Screen changes, so that the screen got not enough horizontal-space, the two stacklayouts should be ordered vertical.

I don't want to do it in code behind.

I search for an solution which only uses the xaml.

Comment: I know that UWP has this, but I am also curious to know if Xamarin currently supports this.

Comment: `solution wich only uses the xaml` : There is no layout that does that, you could write one of course or handle it in code-behind but you ruled that out.

Comment: @Tony Can you give me a a doc or some reference for the uwp? Maybe I can adapt it.

Comment: UWP Adaptive UI XAML https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt590974.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you can't achieve this using ONLY XAML. Certainly, you will need some c# code.
The XAML on Xamarin.Forms is designed to be responsive, and you often define the view properties in a relative mode (instead of absolute).

You can see an example of the behavior you want [at this topic](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation/#StackLayout) where we can see a screen changing the orientation of the StackLayout according to the device orientation (you can use it as your guideline to write your own layout component)

**The screen on portrait mode:**
[image: The screen on portrait mode]

**The screen on landscape mode:**
[image: The screen on landscape mode]

> That is accomplished with the following XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="ResponsiveLayout.StackLayoutPageXaml"
Title="Stack Photo Editor - XAML">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="10" Padding="5" Orientation="Vertical"
        x:Name="outerStack"> <!-- can change orientation to make responsive -->
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout Spacing="5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    WidthRequest="1000">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="Name: " WidthRequest="75"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                        <Entry Text="deer.jpg"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="Date: " WidthRequest="75"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                        <Entry Text="07/05/2015"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="Tags:" WidthRequest="75"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                        <Entry Text="deer, tiger"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Text="Save" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <Image  Source="deer.jpg" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

> Some C# is used to change the orientation of outerStack based on the
>   orientation of the device:

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated (double width, double height){
    base.OnSizeAllocated (width, height);
    if (width != this.width || height != this.height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        if (width > height) {
            outerStack.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        } else {
            outerStack.Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks very much! Too bad that there is no xaml only variant.

Comment: I agree with it. But keep in mind that XAML is a markup language, you can't programming everything on it, unfortunately. I recomend you to see [this presentation of Charles Pretzold at Xamarin Evolve 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6UOrSyhTEE) that helped me a lot! It's an amazing approach about XAML. I became a fan after to watch this.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not possible. I did basically exactly what you want  'manually'. It's not too hard, though. First of all, you'll have to wrap your stack layouts in another `StackLayout`

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App.Views.TestPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="OuterStackLayout">
            <StackLayout>
                <!-- Inner stack layout 1 -->
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <!-- Inner stack layout 2 -->
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Next, you'll have to override `OnSizeAllocated` and set the outer `OuterStackLayout.Orientation` according to your screen orientation

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

    if (SizeHasChanged(width, height)) // elided, just compare width, height with the stored values
    {
        StoreSize(width, height); // store in private members

        if (IsLandscape)
        {
            this.OuterStackLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        }
        else
        {
            this.OuterStackLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
        }
    }
}

public bool IsLandscape => _width > _height;
```

Maybe you'll have to fiddle around with the horizontal options of the inner `StackLayout`s a bit - or other layout parameters, but basically this should do.

Answer (score 1):

Option #1 'Orientation States' - Portrait & Landscape. Use 'OrientationStates' inside visual state manager like so:

Inside .XAML File

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid"
        Margin="10,30,10,10">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OrientationStates">

            <!-- Row & Column Definitions of Grid - [2 Rows, 1 Col = Portrait] & [1 Row, 2 Cols = Landscape] -->
            <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.RowDefinitions"
                            Value="*,*" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnDefinitions"
                            Value="*" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.RowDefinitions"
                            Value="*" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnDefinitions"
                            Value="*,*" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <!-- Change position of stack layouts in grid, to match above stated orientation requirement -->
    <StackLayout x:Name="firstStackLayout">
        <Entry Placeholder="Enter first words" />
        <Button Text="Nothing Happens" />

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>

                <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

                <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout x:Name="secondStackLayout">
        <Entry Placeholder="Enter last words" />
        <Button Text="Still Nothing Happens" />

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>

                <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

                <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

With an added 'OnSizeAllocated()' function in CodeBehind like so:

Inside .XAML.CS File

```
public partial class RegisterPage : ContentPage
{
    public RegisterPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

        var state = (width > height) ? "Landscape" : "Portrait";

        // Call the 'Portrait' & 'Landscape' States in .XAML File
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(myGrid, state);
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(firstStackLayout, state);
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(secondStackLayout, state);
    }
}
```

[OR]

Option #2 The magic bullet - Your **ONLY .XAML File solution** to that problem.

'Orientation Triggers' - Portrait & Landscape.

Use 'OrientationStateTriggers' inside 'State Triggers' in Visual State like so:

Inside .XAML File

```
<Grid Margin="10,30,10,10">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>

            <!-- Row & Column Definitions of Grid - [2 Rows, 1 Col = Portrait] & [1 Row, 2 Cols = Landscape] -->
            <VisualState x:Name="gridPortrait">

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Portrait" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.RowDefinitions"
                            Value="*,*" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnDefinitions" Value="*" />
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="gridLandscape">

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Landscape" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.RowDefinitions"
                            Value="*" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnDefinitions"
                            Value="*,*" />
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>

        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <!-- Change position of stack layouts in grid, to match above stated orientation requirement -->
    <StackLayout>
        <Entry Placeholder="Enter first words" />
        <Button Text="Nothing Happens" />

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>

                <VisualState x:Name="myPortraitState">

                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Portrait" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>

                </VisualState>

                <VisualState x:Name="myLandscapeState">

                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Landscape" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>

                </VisualState>

            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout>
        <Entry Placeholder="Enter last words" />
        <Button Text="Still Nothing Happens" />

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="myPortraitState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Portrait" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="myLandscapeState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <OrientationStateTrigger Orientation="Landscape" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not too late. Using `Xamarin.Essentials` is an easier solution for me.

`Model.cs`

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;
.
.
.
private DisplayOrientation orientation = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation;
public DisplayOrientation Orientation
{
    get => orientation;
    set => orientation = value;
}
```

`View.xaml.cs`

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;
.
.
.
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
    model.Orientation = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation;
}
```

`View.xaml`

```
<ContentPage xmlns:ess="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Essentials;assembly=Xamarin.Essentials">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <!--Model here-->
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="..."
        Binding="{Binding Orientation}"
        Value="{x:Static ess:DisplayOrientation.Portrait}">
            <Setter Property="..." Value="..." />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="..."
        Binding="{Binding Orientation}"
        Value="{x:Static ess:DisplayOrientation.Landscape}">
            <Setter Property="..." Value="..." />
    </DataTrigger>
</ContentPage>
```

Don't forget the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implications.